# Wait for execution of all promises in bluebird

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I want to wait for all promises to resolve or reject, and get results of resolved promises in `.then` and errors in ``

```
'use strict';

const Promise = require('bluebird')

var delayOne = Promise.method((p = 1) => p);

var delayTwo = (p = 1) => {
    throw new Error('asf');
};

Promise.all([delayOne(100), Promise.method(delayTwo)(10), delayOne(300)])
    .then((res) => console.log(res)) // no logs from here
    .catch((e) => console.log(e))
    .done();
```

but I'm getting logs only from `.catch`. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Well, the promise created by `Promise.all` is rejected with the error from the second promise, so the `onfulfilled` callback of `then` won't be called. Why do you expect it to?

Comment: `Promise.all` returns a Promise that resolves when all of the Promises in the array have resolved, but if any promise in the array rejects, the returned promise instead rejects with the reason. This is why you're only seeing logs from `.catch`.

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Promise.all` waits for all promises to *fulfill*, you want to get ones with rejections, you can add `.reflect` on promises you'd like to allow failing:

```
Promise.all([
  delayOne(100), 
  Promise.method(delayTwo)(10).reflect(), // reflect here
  delayOne(300)])
  .then((res) => console.log(res)) // no logs from here
  // don't `.catch(e => console.log(e))` it is not needed
  // done is deprecated, you don't need it
```